# How to run nrwl/nx production build of web app on localhost (NextJS)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nrwl-nx

Is there a way to run nrwl/nx next.js built app for production on localhost?

I tried using `npm i -g serve` and after `serve -s` in the folder of the next app, but the app appears without styles and navigation.

It seems that only index.html is present.

Do I have to use Vercel to deploy or is there a way to just test the performance of the bundled app on localhost?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

You can also run custom commands with your custom server file. The official [documentation is here](https://nx.dev/workspace/run-commands-executor).

```
"production": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
  "options": {
    "command": "node apps/web/server.js"
  }
},
```

**1) STATIC WEBSITE**

From the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#nodejs-server):

> Then, run next build to build your application. Finally, run next start to start the Node.js server. This server supports all features of Next.js.

That means that in `NX` you want to build your project:

```
nx build project-name
```

Then navigate to `dist` folder:

```
cd dist/apps/project-name
```

Then you can [run your project](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#production):

```
npm run start
```

**2) SSR WEBSITE**

Gh05d is kind of correct and if you want to run Next in SSR mode then you have to create a custom server file. You can find documentation how to do that [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) and then the rest of your setup is gonna depend on where and how do you want to deploy your application.

If you are working on a demo application or if your company uses Vercel then you can deploy your application to Vercel without custom `server.js` files.

Here is the official NX [documentation](https://nx.dev/guides/deploy-nextjs-to-vercel):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom server for this. Create a **server.js** file in the root directory of your project. It should look like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3364;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get("*", (req, res) => handle(req, res));

  server.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(` => Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

Then make sure that your **package.json** has these scripts:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  }
}
```

Then you just have to build the app with `npm run build` and then start the app with `npm run start`.

> next build builds the production application in the .next folder. After building, next start starts a Node.js server that supports hybrid pages, serving both statically generated and server-side rendered pages.

Read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server).

**UPDATE**:
Added the correct start script.

Comment: What you did helps but it doesn't solve the problem. People who use NX should follow NX best practices. You can put random `server.js` file in the project but adding custom command is a major mistake. Kind of like if you had a project with CMake in C++ and decided to run the project with your custom command instead. The correct answer is to add custom command exector. https://nx.dev/workspace/run-commands-executor And I am sorry for being a bit toxic but I am really really tired by web dev community. IMHO partial solutions are not solutions.

Comment: Ok sorry, I wasn't aware of this. Will try to read up on NX. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It seems dev in `next({ dev })` was changed to isNextDevCommand